# Generate automatic photo gallery with PHP or Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, photo-gallery, auto-generate

So I have a huge amount of car photos which I have sorted in a structure looking like this (this is an fictive example to demonstrate my principle):

```
Cars > Audi > Sports cars > '5 pictures'

Cars > Audi > Family cars > '3 pictures'

Cars > BMW > Family cars > '5 pictures'
```

I will upload the folder named Cars to my server.

Now what I want is a snippet/script that reads my directory then generate and return html for an simple photoalbum. There is no need for the album to be advanced, I just want to skip writing the photoalbums HTML manually by hand.

I'm guessing that this has been done many times already though I cant find a simple demo of it. I would be willing to pay for it but then I would of course have higher demands regarding the quality of the code.

If anything is unclear please let me know and I will update my question ASAP!

Comment: Please update your post and tell us **what you've tried**, this is not a request forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sry, I just found the answer:

http://davidwalsh.name/generate-photo-gallery